# 1977 Honda CB750K stripped threads

Tags: motorcycle, stripped-thread, helicoil

My overall question is that I recently replaced the oil pan gasket and learned that the threads where the bolts screw into are stripped. I was wondering if I could use a helicoil repair kit or if drilling the holes for the helicoils would strip away too much material/run into something that shouldn't be drilled into.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Anyway you could post up some pics so we can see what things look like? If you can, would you put something in the image so we can tell the exact scale (holding up a tape measure would be AWESOME). This will give us a general idea of whether you can do what you need to do.

Comment: Let me suggest Time-Sert instead of Heli-coil.  They hold better and they don't take as large a hole.